# how to create a copy of my mongo database to remote server

Tags: mongodb

I want to copy the db from a server to another server

since i found some answer that works from my machine to another machine at home
(the 2 machine have the same username):

`ssh -fN -L 27117:localhost:27017 remote_host`

`mongodump  --port 27117 --db dbname --archive | mongorestore --archive`

i tried doing it by

`ssh -fN -L 27117:localhost:27017 myUsername@remote_host`

`mongodump  --port 27117 --db dbname --archive | mongorestore --archive`

but it doest work

i also want to know what does -fN and -L means

thanks in advance maam/sir

Comment: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh

Comment: thanks for this sir.